# How to display the instagram profile picture in front end using html/javascript?

Tags: html, image, frontend, instagram-api

I am using the following link to fetch the instagram profile picture:

https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?__a=1&__d=1

This fetches the dp in the "profile_pic_url" attribute.

When I try to display the image in html like this:

`<img width="70" src= <profile_pic_url> alt="Profile" className="profile-pic-preview"/>`

I get the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instagram changed their CORS policy, so there is no way to display the image directly in your html. The only way would be to use a server side proxy, to bypass the CORS policy.

Comment: Access to image at 'https://instagram.fblr4-3.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/358775499_1708440549584146_4532963113780383511_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s320x320&_nc_ht=instagram.fblr4-3.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=110&_nc_ohc=Iz1qq8MhLK0AX8z8gk9&edm=AKEQFekBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfDDErY9mA4DJK2PCwZirKQQiqjq-5l1QmEH4SfukLV3sw&oe=65271E0F&_nc_sid=29ddf3' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

getting this error after that

Comment: Yeah, sorry, i see now that instagram changed their CORS policy, updated the answer.